# I don't understand DMARC reports regarding my policy

Tags: spf, dkim, dmarc

My DMARC settings seems to not work as expected.

First, a few things to note:

- The domain is `mydomain.com` *(not the real one obviously)* ;
- The domain and mail provider is `gandi.net` ;
- I use **Amazon SES** to send emails from a website using `noreply@mydomain.com` ;
- I use **Gmail** to send and receive emails for `me@mydomain.com` ;

---

The **SPF** record is set as `TXT` on `mydomain.com`:

```
"v=spf1 include:_mailcust.gandi.net include:amazonses.com include:_spf.google.com ~all"
```

- `include:_mailcust.gandi.net` allows **gandi.net** to send emails using `mydomain.com` ;
- `include:amazonses.com` allows **amazonses.com** to send emails using `mydomain.com` ;
- `include:google.com` allows **google.com** to send emails using `mydomain.com` ;
- `~all` allows any other servers to send emails using `mydomain.com` but will result in an SPF check **FAIL** (softfail)

---

The **DMARC** record is set as `TXT` on `_dmarc.mydomain.com`:

```
"v=DMARC1; p=quarantine; sp=reject; pct=5; fo=1; rua=mailto:dmarc@mydomain.com;"
```

- `p=quarantine` delivers emails that failed a SPF/DKIM check and mark them as spam ;
- `sp=reject` rejects emails sent using an address with a subdomain like `noreply@news.mydomain.com` ;
- `pct=5` applies the policy (`p` and not `sp`?) to 5% of emails ;
- `fo=1` sends reports for DKIM failure **OR** SPF failure ;

---

Now the weird things, in this DMARC RUA report:

```xml
  <record>
    <row>
      <source_ip>40.107.12.85</source_ip>
      <count>1</count>
      <policy_evaluated>
        <disposition>none</disposition>
        <dkim>pass</dkim>
        <spf>fail</spf>
      </policy_evaluated>
    </row>
    <identifiers>
      <header_from>mydomain.com</header_from>
    </identifiers>
    <auth_results>
      <dkim>
        <domain>GovSIPF.onmicrosoft.com</domain>
        <result>pass</result>
        <selector>selector1-GovSIPF-onmicrosoft-com</selector>
      </dkim>
      <dkim>
        <domain>mydomain.com</domain>
        <result>pass</result>
        <selector>gm1</selector>
      </dkim>
      <spf>
        <domain>administration.gov.pf</domain>
        <result>pass</result>
      </spf>
    </auth_results>
  </record>
```

- The source IP `40.107.12.85` is from `outlook.com` but I don't use outlook ;
- There is a DKIM block with the domain `GovSIPF.onmicrosoft.com`, GovSIPF is one of my customer ;
- There is an SPF block with the domain `administration.gov.pf` which is the domain they use for their email addresses like `someone@administration.gov.pf` ;

**I don't understand why I see a SPF block with the domain `administration.gov.pf`, does it mean that they sent an email with an address like `someone@mydomain.com` through outlook.com servers ?**

---

Another DMARC report a little different:

```xml
  <record>
    <row>
      <source_ip>202.90.68.50</source_ip>
      <count>1</count>
      <policy_evaluated>
        <disposition>none</disposition>
        <dkim>pass</dkim>
        <spf>fail</spf>
      </policy_evaluated>
    </row>
    <identifiers>
      <header_from>mydomain.com</header_from>
    </identifiers>
    <auth_results>
      <dkim>
        <domain>mydomain.com</domain>
        <result>pass</result>
        <selector>gm1</selector>
      </dkim>
      <spf>
        <domain>mydomain.com</domain>
        <result>softfail</result>
      </spf>
    </auth_results>
  </record>
```

- The source IP `202.90.68.50` is from `mana.pf`, a local ISP but we don't use it ;

Comment: Consider having your DMARC reports processed by a dedicated software or service provider that will automatically issue notifications. Otherwise cost/benefit of reading them quickly becomes excessive. (Thanks for a well-formatted question with all relevant details quoted!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The source IP 40.107.12.85 is from outlook.com but I don't use outlook ;

The `<source_ip>` value is the IP where the original email came from.

It does not necessarily need to be a server you use.

> There is a DKIM block with the domain GovSIPF.onmicrosoft.com, GovSIPF is one of my customer ;

DKIM check *passed*. This is a strong indication that the email was sent using Outlook.

Notice that there is a second DKIM *pass* auth block for *mydomain.com* too.

> There is an SPF block with the domain administration.gov.pf(...)

SPF checks *passed* too. This means that the Outlook IP in `<source_ip>` is authorized to send emails **@administration.gov.pf*.

> (...)does it mean that they sent an email with an address like someone@mydomain.com through outlook.com servers ?

Yes.

And since you don't use Outlook, this most likely was a forwarded email send from one of your servers. DMARC checks pass for the email because the DKIM authentication result for *mydomain.com* pass (the result is “in alignment”).

Answer (score 1):

You get the report when someone uses your `From:` and the recipient is respecting your request to have this reported.
The report does not necessarily indicate which of those messages were newly originating from machines under your control, and which records pertain to **your messages that have been forwarded**. You have to process that report yourself with your local knowledge, ideally in some automated fashion. Note that you cannot with certainty tell which message it was, there might have been a significant delay between their receipt and forwarding - only limited by how long you have been using this DKIM key.

If they left your signature intact (DKIM for your domain is still passing), and your signature is signing a reasonable selection of headers, this does not indicate abuse. As long as your messages were not for legal reasons restricted in where they should be forwarded, there is nothing to do here.

> does it mean that they sent an email with an address like
> someone@mydomain.com through outlook.com servers

Certainly looks like it, since your first example even has their signature added, and if you lookup the SPF & MX record of that domain, you can tell they indeed usually use outlook for both incoming and outgoing mail. Note that this does not have to have been a manual action, a mailbox in that domain might be setup to simply forward everything.